# Can't uninstall mysql-server because : Script SACSrv is broken

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I want to install maven on my computer but when I start the installation, an error occurs concerning mysql-server. Since I don't need mysql-server on my computer, I decide to uninstall it but I face the same problem, the same error. I guess the problem comes from the SACSrv script but I have no idea of the usefulness of this script, or even its location.

Thank you very much for your help

This is for an Ubuntu device.
I've tried to purge, autoremove, and reinstall but that's the same result.

```
$ sudo apt remove mysql-server
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
Le paquet « mysql-server » n'est pas installé, et ne peut donc être supprimé
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 13 non mis à jour.
1 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Paramétrage de mysql-server-5.7 (5.7.26-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) ...
insserv: Script SACSrv is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script SACSrv is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script SACSrv is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script SACSrv is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script SACSrv is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script SACSrv is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script SACSrv is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
insserv: Script Srv is broken: incomplete LSB comment.
insserv: missing `Required-Stop:'  entry: please add even if empty.
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) while connecting to the MySQL server
Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.
mysql_upgrade failed with exit status 11
dpkg: erreur de traitement du paquet mysql-server-5.7 (--configure) :
 le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie d'état 1
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
 mysql-server-5.7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SACSrv script was on /etc/init.d, I've always no idea about it usefulness.
Indeed, 'Required-Stop' entry was missing (I don't know how and why).
I've copy-paste the 'Require-start' line and rename to 'Require-stop' and my purge works fine.